# Static Method on Domain/Model Object with Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, repository

I have separate repository classes for each entity. Now I would like to implement few static methods on domain object which uses repository instance, but the drawback of this approach is that, I have to hold repository instance on the static variable(which not works well on web application) or I have to create new instance on each static method. Is there any better approach for this(i.e. to implement static method on domain class with repository instance)? please share your ideas.

Base repository:

```
public abstract class AbstractRepository<TEntity> : IabstractRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : EntityObject
{
    protected CivilRegistryEntities civilContext;

    public AbstractRepository()
    {
        civilContext = CivilRegistryEntities.Instance; // Per HTTP request singletone.
    }

    // Other method implementation goes here.
}
```

Per entity repository:

```
public class BirthReportRepository : AbstractRepository<BirthReport>
{

}
```

Domain/Entity/Model object:

```
public partial class BirthReport
{
    //Not works well in web application.
    private static BirthReportRepository repository = new BirthReportRepository();

    public static BirthReport Method1()
    {
        return repository.SomeMethod();
    }

    public static BirthReport Method2()
    {
        return repository.SomeOtherMethod();
    }

    // Other methods(both static and instance) goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static mutable state is horrible. Period. The repository contains a context and a context contains tons of mutable states. Besides that, contexts are supposed to have a short life cycle. And: I think that your domain *classes* should have nothing to do with repositories. This is pseudo encapsulation. Instead, let domain *services* handle Method1, method2.

You may consider using an IoC container to inject a context into your repositories and a repository into your domain services. The IoC container could also handle the life cycles of contexts and repositories. For web, an instance per request is common.

Comment: The repository contains low level operations(LINQ to SQL) and the base repository(AbstractRepository<TEntity>) implements basic CRUD operations. I think handling all methods directly on the domain class will be simply a duplication of code! well, the IoC might be a good option.

Comment: _simply a duplication of code_ I'm not sure what you mean, is that good or bad? Anyway, you can harbour static methods anywhere. If you want to use static methods (which can be perfectly reasonable) I would prefer to put them in a static class that clearly is a utility (or service) class. But apart from that, I think that keeping your contexts short-lived is good practice. Also keeping static methods stateless.

Comment: insert, update select-by-primary key, select all, refresh are few of the common method which I don't want to repeat on each domain object. Hence I created base repository to do these tasks and derived repositories to do any other low level tasks. These are not static.

Comment: _keeping your contexts short-lived is good practice_ . This is what I want to do...but still having a static method would be better; specially for finder methods. for ex: BirthReport.FindById(1) or BirthReport.FindAll(). These are quit meaningful methods but the problem is the repository here. Other than the finder, all other are instance methods. I don't feel it good to have instance for these methods.

Comment: Sorry if I'm disturbing you. I am new to these stuffs. I want to write my code in the best possible ways. I appreciate your time and patience.

Comment: You would repeat your code anyway if you put a static method like FindById in each domain class. I think my main objection is that it obscures responsibilities. It's not the domain object that does the job, it's the repository. It's not a domain class's responsibility to fetch and save (like active record), it's the repository's. I would prefer to make my code self-explanatory when it comes to responsibilities (and more).